# How(and where) does the native code get loaded after JIT compilation?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, assembly, reverse-engineering

I have an app, written in .net(C#, 64-bit), I also have a DLL(written in C++) which I want to load at runtime and call specific functions from the main application(from within the DLL). To do that, I'd have to find the native code of this .net app and declare a function pointer to the function.

Now, I've already walked through the PE header and the metadata, found the RVA of the wanted function, however it gets me to the IL(bytecode) implementation instead of the native one(which is called at runtime). After some debugging I've managed to find the function's native(ASM) code, mapped in 64-bit address space, which I'm able to call from the DLL but I can't figure out how I could find this function dynamically(after every time the IL code runs through the JITC).

Is there any way to get information about how/where in memory the JITC loaded the native code? I couldn't really find anything relevant in the PE header regarding this.

Comment: JIT compilers normally write machine code directly into *dynamically allocated* memory pages with write+exec permission, and treat that as a function pointer.  e.g. with `VirtualAlloc` or `new` + `VirtualProtect` on Windows.  IDK how .net specifically handles things to make linking work, but you'll probably only find it at runtime, not with anything from the file metadata / symbol table.

Comment: It is not obvious why you are trying to do this the wrong way.  Google "how to call a C# method from C++" to get somewhere.

Comment: @user2864740 : I'm making an external script tool(to automatize input) for a basic .net game so modifying the .net source is not option(and I don't want to edit the executable itself either). This means, I can't expose the assembly to COM, can't host it(game has to be running) and can't "make it" export its functions.

Comment: There's a hidden assumption here: is there even an answer? Or is this essentially unpredictable? ASLR for instance makes addresses intentionally random. But even if it wasn't intentional, any Microsoft patch might invalidate static assumptions. Also, another assumption is that there exists a single implementation. I could imagine .Net recompiling a function in light of profiling information.

Comment: I don't think this can be considered an answer to this, but `ICorDebugFunction::GetNativeCode` actually returns a pointer to the JIT'ed method of given code chunks. Managed to get it working through a pipe server, I imagine this is only good for serious debugging purposes but it will make do until I find something better. Also, there seems to be some kind of MethodTable that gets generated at compile time, haven't looked into it yet but it's mentioned in the .net core documentation-

Comment: @AdamSchauer - Consider adding such as an answer. While it's a very fringe question/approach, it may provide relevant leads to someone else in the future.. (comments in questions without answers probably have a low read rate.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of research I've found [ICorDebugFunction::GetNativeCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/debugging/icordebugfunction-getnativecode-method) which will return the JIT'ed function's address(given it's been compiled). Managed to get it working through a pipe server.

For anyone who's trying to accomplish something similar as me, you might want to look into how objects are handled in the memory(I imagine it might be different depending on the compiler/.net framework), they all seem to have pointers to tables that contain JIT'ed (member) function addresses with their RID(which can be found in the PE header as well).